# Debug issues in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, python-3.5

I use Pycharm as my IDE for Python 3.5 scripting.

However, sometimes when I hit the debug for a file named main.py, it shows up as `pytest in main.py` and the debugger fails. Other times, debugger runs in the normal mode.

What does `pytest in main.py` mean and how do I get back to normal debugging mode? Please see attached image.

The name of the file in the attached image is `main.py`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something in the file (a `test_*` function probably) confuses PyCharm and makes it believe the file contains `pytest` test methods. Use **Run | Run ...** menu to create a pure Python run configuration or switch to `unittest` test runner in **Settings | Tools | Integrated Tools | Default test runner** if you don't use `pytest` at all in your project.